# Powershell - Delete all items except those in specific subdirectories

Tags: powershell

I have a directory containing a load of subdirectories and files. 
I need to delete all files except those under SubFolder1.

```
Initial State:                       Desired Output:

\                                    \
|_Folder1                            |_Folder1
| |_File1.txt                          |_SubFolder1
| |_File2.xml                            |_File3.csv
| |_SubFolder1                           |_File4.exe
| | |_File3.csv
| | |_File4.exe
| |_Subfolder2
|_Folder2
| |_ <more files here>
|_Folder3 (etc)
```

So here's what I tried:

```
Remove-Item * -exclude Folder1\Subfolder1\*
```

And I get a warning like this:

```
Confirm
The item at C:\foo\Folder1 has children and the -recurse parameter was not specified. 
If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
```

When I specify `-recurse`, it deletes every file, and seems to ignore my filters.

What's going on, and what's the correct way of doing this?

Edit: 
I've included a zip file which contains an [example folder structure](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15385515/foo.zip) as above. If you want to test a solution, please try it against there. I've also included a second zip file which has the [desired output](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15385515/output.zip), so you can check if it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there's a simpler solution, but this function should do the trick:

```
function Clean-Folder
{
    param(
        [string]$rootfolder,
        [string[]]$excluded
    )
    $rootfolder = resolve-path $rootfolder
    Push-Location $rootFolder
    if($excluded -notmatch "^\s*$")
    {
        $excluded = Resolve-Path $excluded
    }
    $filesToDel = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse
    # Excluding files in the excluded folder
    foreach($exclusion in $excluded)
    {
        $filesToDel = $filesToDel |?{$_.fullname -notlike ("{0}\*" -f $exclusion)}
        # Excluding parent folders of the excluded folder
        while($exclusion -notmatch "^\s*$")
        {
            $filesToDel = $filesToDel |?{$_.fullname -ne $exclusion}
            $exclusion = Split-Path -parent $exclusion
        }
    }
    $filesToDel |Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Pop-Location
}
```

Basically, what it does is recursively list all the items in your folder, then remove the one you want to keep, its sub-items and all its parent folders. Finally, it deletes the remaining list.

Just declare the function above, then:

```
Clean-Folder -rootfolder <path> -excluded <folder you want to exclude>
```

Edit: made rootfolder accept relative paths, and excluded accept a list of folders

Comment: Nice work @poorkenny! It's certainly the closest so far, and the only one that matches my required output. Some suggestions though: Is there a way to make the "excluded" parameter work like the the one for "Remove-Item" (ie. take a comma separated array of excludes, rather than a single path). It would also be nice to allow relative paths, instead of the full ones.

Comment: Cool. In the absence of a non-broken -Recurse parameter from Microsoft, I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\folder1\ -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) -notlike 'c:\folder1\subfolder1*' | sort length -descending | remove-item
```

Comment: +1 for filter array with -notlike, and the trick behind the sort! Very nice.

Comment: It Needs just a change: 'c:\folder1\subfolder1*'

Comment: Not a Posh expert, but the one working for me is `(Get-ChildItem c:\folder1\ -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) |where { $_ -notlike 'c:\folder1\subfolder1*'} | sort length -descending | remove-item`

Comment: I swear to God.. the time it took me to search, find, and read up this point, I would have already have deleted all my files except some from a folder simply using the GUI. Ridiculous there isn't a built-in command such as:

rm * -except <insert_pattern_here>

Answer (score 2):

You could call two consecutive commands:

```
Remove-Item * -recurse -exclude Folder1
Remove-Item Folder1\* -recurse -exclude Subfolder1
```

First you remove everything except Folder1. After that you remove everything in Folder1 except Subfolder1. This way you avoid having to specify a subsubfolder to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a why or a correct way, but I did think of a workaround. You could try piping the output of a get-childitem cmdlet to the remove-item cmdlet (not specifically tested so may need some slight adjusting):

```
get-childitem -Recurse | where fullname -notlike *SubFolder1* | remove-item -recurse
```

Comment: That won't work, because Folder1 is not excluded by your filter, causing it to be recursively deleted, which in turn deletes SubFolder1

Comment: I was about to post the very same thing. It's like get-childitem and remove-item work from the top down, instead of the bottom up...

Comment: Ahh, I thought you were running the command from within "folder1"

Answer (score 0):

Just ditch that wildcard on the exclude its :

Remove-Item * -exclude Folder1\Subfolder1\

Comment: Hmmm... I've created a dummy folder structure mimicking the example above. It's on my Dropbox here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15385515/foo.zip... When I run your command without the wildcard, I still get all folders deleted. Can you try it?

Comment: My bad the extra level of nesting is causing it.Investigating

Comment: try Remove-Item * -exclude Folder1,Folder1\Subfolder1\

Comment: No good. This leaves all the child directories and files in Folder1. I've edited the question to include a "desired output" zip file too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally I've solved it:

```
Get-Childitem folder_for_clear_path -Exclude folder_for_exclude_name | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

edited:
For this issue, use the next code:

```
Get-Childitem C:\foo -exclude Folder1 | Remove-Item -recurse 
Get-Childitem C:\foo\Folder1 -exclude SubFolder1 | Remove-Item -recurse
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. I end up with an empty root folder every time. Can you give an exact syntax which works with the example structure?

Comment: Sorry. In beginning I didn't understand right your conditions. The next 2 lines of code do logic you need:
this `get-childitem C:\foo -exclude Folder1 | remove-item -recurse` and then this
`get-childitem C:\foo\Folder1 -exclude SubFolder1 | remove-item -recurse`

Comment: Is it helpful for you?