# How to delete files from multiple folders excluding couple of folders?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, powershell-5.1

We have a situation where the cp.exe and cp.dll are getting copied in build artifacts of all the folders and we want them only to be part of PS.Manager.Service and PS.A.Service folder/Artifacts.

From rest all the folders both the cp.exe and its cp.dll must be deleted. I tried doing that with the below script but It is not working. I am not sure what am I missing here.

Any suggestions would really help.

Thanks.

```
$SourceDirectory = "e:\cache\Agent03\2\s"
$EXcludeManagerFolder = "e:\cache\Agent03\2\s\PS.Manager.Service"
$EXcludeAFolder = "e:\cache\Agent03\2\s\PS.A.Service"

gci -path "$SourceDirectory" -Include "cp.exe, cp.dll" -Exclude "$EXcludeManagerFolder","$EXcludeAFolder " -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15246602/7571258 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/61934452/7571258 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744489/how-to-exclude-files-by-part-of-directory-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685078/how-to-delete-files-from-multiple-folders-excluding-couple-of-folders#comment128391074_72685078) already commented, `Include`, `Exclude` (and also `Filter`) only work on the objects Name, not the full path.

The easiest way is to create a regex string with the folders you need to exclude so you can match (or `-notmatch` in this case)

```
$SourceDirectory = "e:\cache\Agent03\2\s"
# create a regex of the files and/or folders to exclude
$exclude = 'PS.Manager.Service', 'PS.A.Service'  # foldernames to exclude
# each item will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

(Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirectory -Include 'cp.exe', 'cp.dll' -File -Recurse).FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $notThese } |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, it worked smoothly and as expected.